# A Perl User Input program can't be executed in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, user-input

I'm a beginner of Perl, using Ubuntu 12.04 as my operating system.

My perl version is v5.14.2.

I wrote a simple program to read user input then print it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "please enter your name:";
my $name = ;
print "\n";
print "hello, $name\n";
```

When I tried to execute this program it turned out to be like this,

```
syntax error at input.pl line 3, near "=;"
Execution of input.pl aborted due to compilation errors`
```

But this is a sample code which I copied from a perl textbook, so it shouldn't be any mistake in the code.

Comment: That line should be `my $name = <STDIN>;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel like I'm a idiot. Maybe I should change a textbook....

Comment: Please make sure to actually copy-paste code and error message. They don't match.

Comment: I forgot to paste the "#!/usr/bin/perl" line.... Already added it! Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: What is the book? Are you reading it from an actual book or from a web site? It sounds like a web site that is interpreting the <STDIN> as an HTML tag. You should report this to the publisher or web site owner.

Comment: @DaveCross This really explain everything.It's a copy of a website, I'll try contact the website owner.Thank you!

Comment: @Nemo Thanks for your recommandation!Lots of people tell me to get *Learning Perl 6th edition*,too.I'll go buy one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that code makes no sense, as the compiler tells you:
    my $name = ;

write something like:

```
my $name = <>;
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more explicit:

```
my $name = <STDIN>;
```

which reads from the standar input, or:

```
my $name = readline(*STDIN);
```

If you do `my $name = <>;`, it will read either from a file specified on the command line or from `STDIN` if no file is specified

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do learn a lot!